# Understanding LD options in make file

Tags: makefile, ld

I recently downloaded the graclus software. While trying to install it I had to be complete the makefile.in with some options.I figured out other options but I couldn't find what do we write for the LDOPTIONS.

Can anybody help me out in figuring what do I fill in the options used by the compiler?
Help will be truly appreciated.

//Here is the makefile.in

```
# Which compiler to use
CC = g++

# What optimization level to use
OPTFLAGS = -O2 -fPIC

# What options to be used by the compiler
COPTIONS = -DNUMBITS=32

# What options to be used by the loader
LDOPTIONS =

# What archiving to use 
AR = ar rv

# What to use for indexing the archive
RANLIB = ranlib

ARCH = P4SSE2

LAPACK = -llapack_$(ARCH)

ARPACK = -lcarpack_$(ARCH)

ATLAS  = -latlas_$(ARCH)

CBLAS  = -lcblaswr -lcblas -lblas -lmyf2c

GSL = -lgslcblas -lgsl

SPARSE = -lsparse

UTIL = -lmyutil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Makefile you provided is just an excerpt and you've not mentioned what package or library you're compiling it with, I'm just making a wild-guess here.

**LDOPTIONS** could serve a similar puprose as the commonly used variable **LDFLAGS** which provides a way to specify extra flags to the linker. It depends on the linker you use. If you're using gcc, then you can run **man ld** to see the list of linker options.

Comment: Thanks it was to be left as it is!

Comment: thanks man,  while this question was irrelevent!  you'r answer gave me an idea of what i may be doing wrong .